# multi column article display module for joomla

Tags: joomla, module

Does anyone know where I could find a FREE module that displays articles along with images on multiple columns like here http://raxo.org/demo.html ?

I've been on this for a few days now, I just know there is something out there..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Gavick News Show Pro. http://tools.gavick.com/newshowpro.html

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, back then, I edited the template myself. Couldn't find a module that did exactly what I wanted.